# New SSD gets errors when booting

Tags: boot, ssd, sata

I recently bought a 120Gb Kingston SSDNowV300 and I installed Ubuntu 13.10 onto it. When I boot, it pauses at a flashing cursor for a huge amount of time. Changing the boot flags to text showed a bunch of errors:

```
Jan 15 17:39:01 speshmesh kernel: [  142.179159] ata3.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Jan 15 17:39:01 speshmesh kernel: [  142.179209] ata3.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
Jan 15 17:39:01 speshmesh kernel: [  142.179259] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Jan 15 17:39:01 speshmesh kernel: [  142.179312] ata3.00: cmd 60/28:c8:00:48:c6/00:00:0b:00:00/40 tag 25 ncq 20480 in
Jan 15 17:39:01 speshmesh kernel: [  142.179312]          res 41/84:d0:08:4a:c6/84:00:0b:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Jan 15 17:39:01 speshmesh kernel: [  142.179392] ata3.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Jan 15 17:39:01 speshmesh kernel: [  142.179442] ata3.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
Jan 15 17:39:01 speshmesh kernel: [  142.179492] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Jan 15 17:39:01 speshmesh kernel: [  142.179545] ata3.00: cmd 60/08:d0:08:4a:c6/00:00:0b:00:00/40 tag 26 ncq 4096 in
Jan 15 17:39:01 speshmesh kernel: [  142.179545]          res 41/84:d0:08:4a:c6/84:00:0b:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
```

This repeated over and over again until it eventually reached the last one and then finished the rest of booting:

```
Jan 15 17:39:01 speshmesh kernel: [  142.180557] ata3.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Jan 15 17:39:01 speshmesh kernel: [  142.180607] ata3.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
Jan 15 17:39:01 speshmesh kernel: [  142.180659] ata3: hard resetting link
Jan 15 17:39:01 speshmesh kernel: [  142.180708] ata3: nv: skipping hardreset on occupied port
Jan 15 17:39:01 speshmesh kernel: [  142.648026] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
```

It also occasionally hung for a long time at `[  100.247175] ata3: EH complete`.

What could the problem be? Is it just a faulty SSD?

Comment: I have the same problem and I am kind of surprised that no one has responded. Like you I get the same errors, and the computer freezes until EH complete shows up. Something else that occurs is that this is happening when my drive is filling up. It is almost as if the OS is writting to a bad sector, that technically should have been marked as so, but it isn't. If i delete bunch of the newly written data, then it stops doing it.

Comment: I contacted Kingston support and they said that it was because the SSD was getting of out sync with the motherboard and CPU.  What solved it for me (or at least sped up booting a great deal) was to disable IDE devices in the BIOS. It's a bit impractical but the only thing that worked

Answer (score 0):

The cause is reported in the log message above "ICRC", you should check cables first. It is the most likely culprit to the issue you are having.

The reply from Kingston sounds very strange, there is nothing that can get out-of-sync in there, the CRC errors are caused on the physical transport between the two SATA interfaces (disk and motherboard) and if they are out-of-sync the entire disk is lost and becomes unreadable.

After a few failures Linux will downgrade the speed to 3Gbps or disable NCQ, both of which will severely impact the performance but will also reduce the change to see the CRC errors as the lower speeds and lower IO rate will increase the chance to withstand low error rate.